# DateTimePicker wrong value with custom format "HH:mm"

Tags: c#, winforms, datetimepicker

In a WinForms application I have some DateTimePicker controls with custom format "HH:mm".

I need to get the hour (HH part) of these controls but if I introduced the hour as "8" instead of "08", Value.Hour property is returning 0.
The control is showing "08:00" but value is still 0.

Is this an error? Any way to solve it?

Thanks!

FJ

Comment: How do you set this value?

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: In a WinForms project add a DateTimePicker to the Form. Set Format property to "Custom" and CustomFormat to "HH:mm". Set value to 00:00. At Leave event get datetimepicker1.Value.Hour to a variable. Run the program, set focus to datetimepicker1, type "8" and press TAB. Al Leave event Value.Hour will be 0 instead of 8.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I've got a solution: using ValueChanged event instead of Leave event although I would prefer at Leave.

Regards,

FJ